# Bower hanging when installing dependencies on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, bower, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to install a bunch of dependencies using Bower on Ubuntu 14.04. The installation hangs at a semi random point (one of jQuery, closure-library or closure compiler). Versions are below, along with the bower.json (anonymised).

Node v0.10.35
NPM v1.4.28
Bower v1.3.12

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "redacted",
  "version": "0.12.2",
  "homepage": "redacted",
  "description": "redacted",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.3.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.10",
    "angular-cookie": "~4.0.6",
    "bootstrap": "~3.2.0",
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.0",
    "signalr": "*",
    "angular-translate": "~2.4.0",
    "fallback": "https://github.com/dolox/fallback.git#v2",
    "angularjs-scroll-glue": "~0.0.1",
    "angular-swfobject": "~1.0.2",
    "swfobject": "*",
    "angular-moment": "~0.8.3",
    "momentjs": "~2.8.3",
    "moment-timezone": "~0.2.2",
    "angular-uuid4": "~0.2.0",
    "font-awesome": "~4.2.0",
    "angular-strap": "~2.1.4",
    "angular-motion": "~0.3.4",
    "angularjs-toaster": "~0.4.9",
    "angular-hotkeys": "https://github.com/chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys.git#1.4.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "es5-shim": "~4.0.3",
    "closure-compiler": "~0.2.6",
    "closurelibrary": "*",
    "closure-library-externs": "git@github.com:google/closure-compiler.git#v20140814",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "~1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Can anyone spot anything wrong with the `bower.json`, or know of any incompatibilities between bower and Ubuntu with these versions?

Sample line from `bower install` output at a point where it hangs (as mentioned, the exact point it hangs changes each time, though it appears to happen on `resolved` most of the time).

`bower fallback#v2  resolved https://github.com/dolox/fallback.git#0568407bc2`

Comment: Replicated on a Ubuntu VM (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS), host machine running OSX Mountain Lion (where I'm unable to replicate the issue).

Comment: I've just tried installing everything individually and that seems to have worked fine as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an `npm-debug.log` I can't definitely diagnose this, but it sure looks like some of the install errors/race conditions that used to plague older versions of npm -- before 2.1.

There have been a lot of improvements to npm -- especially around conflicts and race conditions during install -- since 1.4.28. Can you try updating your npm installation?

To update npm, run `npm -g install npm@latest`

For some Linux distributions (Debian/Ubuntu and RedHat/CentOS), the latest node version provided by the distribution may lag behind the stable version. [Here are instructions from NodeSource](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions) on getting the latest node.